# When to create a new git branch vs commiting updates

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

I am quite new to using git. My question is regarding when it is sensible to create a new branch vs committing changes.

If I make changes to my code, I can make those changes under a new branch or I can commit and push those changes in the existing branch.

If I can view the history and compare changes over time with both methods - the question is when it is sensible to make a new branch?

Comment: Have a look at [this git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). It's a common workflow to have one central development branch, and branch feature branches off if you begin to implement a new feature, then merge it back to develop when the feature is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your team/organization's development processes more than anything. Typically with Version Control Systems (not just git, but others like svn as well), the *typical* work flow is that you have your main `develop` branch as your baseline. Whenever you need to fix a bug, add a new feature, or test some experimental code that you would like to keep around, you should simply make a new branch - `myBranch` based off of the latest version of `develop`.

Once you've tested your code, peer reviewed it, etc. (subject to your team's processes) you would then merge your changes back to `develop`.

So to answer your question in short, the general rule of thumb is that if you need to make changes to any functionality, you should be working off of a branch. It's a pretty standard development work flow in software development. Get in the habit of working off of branches, there's no penalty for doing so and it is **encouraged**. This keeps your baseline intact and ensures that code changes are being reviewed before being pushed in.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on different influential factors. Such as your purpose of work, are you working on team or an individual project.

Mostly when we are working in team project/task and my work is reviewed and merged to master branch by my team lead / senior colleague, it always expected that we always keep updated from new push in `master branch` and also need to start `new branch` for new task. And also our branch name should be align to our related work. Say i am working on user login task so it always good to name my work branch as `feature-user-login` so that my reviewer always can get easy idea what i trying to push in master from the branch name. And also we must need to add meaningful `commit messages` so that my other team members can easily understand what is actually happening in these piece of code.

When you are working on single project and you are the only contributor of your project, its true that there is actually no need to keep multiple branch. You can complete your whole work by a single `master branch` or for some tracking purpose you can maintain two/three branch. But it always better to create `new branch` when you are doing different module of work or fixing any bug. Just for your own clarity.